# Can C# do Read Stream from assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

Im totally new to C# and .Net and I did some research about Streams and wonder if I can Read stream some data inside an Assembly.

I have look into multiple resources but was not able to find some clues or answers and was hoping somebody can steer me into the right direction.

Comment: I will check this one out, thank you for the response over the weekend. @IłyaBursov

Answer (score 0):

with this method and related namespace you can read stream from assembly

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
```

Comment: Do you have any simple code examples that i can follow through?

Comment: some sample easy code are there :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getstream?view=net-6.0